# React Number Format adding suffix to the value

Tags: reactjs

How can I avoid react number format adding suffix to the value ?

Here is a working example on Codepen with console.log
https://codepen.io/Punisher49/pen/jOVoXqQ?editors=1011

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }
  render(){
  console.log(this.state.value)
    
    return (
      <div>
          <NumberFormat thousandSeparator={true} value = {this.state.value} 
            onChange={ event => this.setState({value: event.target.value})} suffix={'$'} className="some" inputmode="numeric" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I can use `event.target.value.slice(0, -1)` but I think it is just a workaround, not a proper solution. Because I can have a long suffix or change suffix dynamically. In that case to support my solution will be problematic

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Do you want to remove the suffix?

Comment: I don't want $ to appear in my state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onValueChange` prop which receives the [values](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#values-object) object to update the state with just the value.

```
<NumberFormat
  thousandSeparator={true}
  value={this.state.value}
  suffix="$"
  onValueChange={({ value }) => {
    this.setState({ value })
  }}
/>
```